# Prevent sweet.js from adding numbers to variables

Tags: javascript, sweet.js

Sweet.js always adds numbers to the end of the output.  In most of the javascript I am generating, this is not necessary.  Is there a way to configure sweet.js to not add numbers to the end of the parameters?

```
    // Example Output
    module.exports = multiply;
    function multiply(a_31, b_32, c_33) {
        console.log('hey')
        if (Object.prototype.toString.call(a_31) !== "[object Array]") throw new Error("Must be array:" + a_31);
        if (Object.prototype.toString.call(c_33) !== "[object Array]") throw new Error("Must be array:" + c_33);
        return a_31 * c_33;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sweet.js currently does *very* aggressive variable renaming. There's an [issue](https://github.com/sweet-js/sweet-core/issues/514) to limit the renaming to only the cases where there are multiple bindings with the same name.